# Error to run a Maven with JUnit project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

When I am trying to run a Maven with JUnit test in an eclipse project I've got this ERROR below:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building exemplo-maven 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ exemplo-maven ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\vcamargo\workspace\exemplo-maven\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ exemplo-maven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ exemplo-maven ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\vcamargo\workspace\exemplo-maven\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ exemplo-maven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ exemplo-maven ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\vcamargo\workspace\exemplo-maven\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ exemplo-maven ---
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.12.4/surefire-booter-2.12.4.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.12.4/maven-surefire-common-2.12.4.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.9/maven-reporting-api-2.0.9.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-toolchain/2.0.9/maven-toolchain-2.0.9.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.1/maven-plugin-annotations-3.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.470 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-27T10:08:30-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project exemplo-maven: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): RSA premaster secret error: SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Following my pom.xml below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.algaworks.curso</groupId>
    <artifactId>exemplo-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <killAfter>-1</killAfter>
                    <mainClass>com.algaworks.curso.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My main class:

```
package com.algaworks.curso;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Maven");
    }

}
```

And finally my test class:

```
package com.algaworks.curso;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FibonacciTest {

    @Test
    public void deve_retornar_fibonacci_posicao_1() {
        assertEquals(1L, 1L);
    }

}
```

When I run my test class individually it runs perfect. And if I try to run a Maven project without test (goal: exec:java) it runs perfect too.

The error occur just when I try to run the Maven project with the JUnit test (goal: clean project).

Comment: what happens when you try to run it from the terminal ?

Comment: I don,t know how to run it from the terminal. I am using the Maven plugin into Eclipse, and if I configure to run without the test (goal: exec:java) it run perfectly.

Comment: Try to run `mvn clean install` from the project directory which includes the `pom.xml` (after installing maven)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs you've posted it seems like issue is not with your JUnit test cases, but with your maven not able to download few artifacts..In the repo I could see a maven surefire booter jar of required version..I guess there is some issue with network firewalls or connectivity...can we try reconnecting to network and then running a goal ?

Answer (score 1):

Error says dependencies which are directly or indirectly used by surefire plug-in can not be resolved. i never had this error but, delete your maven-surefire-plugin folder from location : ".m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins"
and re-run the build which will automatically re-download all the plugin files.
make sure to have aback up of the folder before deleting so that you can analyse what were missing.